# How can i create these shapes with java

Tags: java

```
package assignment.pkg3;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Assignment3 {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner stdIn = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("What integer length do you want: ");
    int length = stdIn.nextInt();

    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
      for (int j = ((length - 1) - i); j > 0; j--) {
        System.out.print(" ");
      }
      for (int a = 0; a <= i; a++) {
        System.out.print("*");
      }
      System.out.println();
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
      for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
        System.out.print(" ");
      }
      for (int a = length; a > i; a--) {
        System.out.print("*");
      }
      for (int b = (length - 1); b > i; b--) {
        System.out.print("*");
      }
      System.out.println();
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
      for (int j = 0; j <= i; j++) {
        for (int k = 0; k < i; k++) {
          System.out.print(" ");
        }
        for (int a = 0; a <= i; a++) {
          System.out.print("*");
        }
        System.out.println();
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Hi, I need help making this 3rd shape.. I don't even know how to start it. I did the other 3 pretty well. (except I have the spaces wrong on shape D). Can anyone help me find somewhere to start. (BTW I'm in a beginner java class so I can't put anything in there that we haven't learned. So sticking to for loops is basically all we can essentially use lol) 
[Here is link to pic](http://i.imgur.com/0ms9bWc.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to execute this one & check -

```
for (int i = 0; i < length/2; i++){

            for (int j = 0; j < length; j++){
                System.out.print("*" + " ");
            }
            System.out.println("");

            for (int k = 0; k < length-1; k++){
                System.out.print(" " + "*");
            }
            System.out.println("");
        }
```

Hope this will solve your problem.

Comment: That works really well! except its missing the last row on the bottom haha. But i'll see if i can figure that out on my own. :)